# How to generate array of string with the weekdays from the current weekday using moment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, momentjs

Want to generate the dynamic array of string with the weekdays as a value inside the array for the list which I am using.

Required:=> If current weekday is Monday then array should be

```
['today','tomorrow','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
```

Array should be dynamic based on the current day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate array with the weekday as a string here is the code.

```
const daysArray = () => {
const weekArray = [...Array(7 - moment().weekday())];
const today = new Date();
return weekArray.map((week, index) => {
  const dayName = moment(today)
    .add(index, "days")
    .calendar()
    .split(" at")[0];
  const date = moment(today).add(index, "days").format(DATE_FORMAT);

  return { value: dayName, name: dayName, date };
}); 

};
```

This will generate the array of object with dynamic weekdays inside it. If you will return only **dayName** then you'll get you're desired result.